# How to remove ' from the concatenated output in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

1. I've been trying to insert multiple data into table with the value "DB1.DBX" concatenated to an incrementing int val.

Following is my code that concatenates DB1.DBX to incrementing int value i

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int len = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        const string db = "DB1.DBX";
        con.Open();
        for (int i=1; i<len; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1(Address) values('DBX.DB1''"+i.ToString()+"')",con);
            smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Data inserted Successfully!");

        con.Close();
    }
```

But there is an extra ' that gets concatenated to the output.

[image: Following is the output]

Comment: Just **don't build queries by concatenating strings**. Use prepared statements.

Comment: "*But there is an extra `'`*" - of course there is because you have it in your code:  `''"`. Get rid of the two single quotes in there. But a **much** better solution is to **not** concatenate strings as Denys said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using concatenation of string to build queries is a wrong idea overall. You'd better look uppon others answer than mine. But here some reworks on your code that should work just fine and won't be sensitive to SQL injection:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int len = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    const string db = "DB1.DBX";
    con.Open();
    for (int i=1; i<len; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1(Address) values('"+ db + i + "')",con);
        smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Data inserted Successfully!");

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: This *particular* piece of code wasn't subject to SQL Injection anyway. But the *habit* of constructing SQL code through string concatenation raises the significant risk that the OP will write an injectable query in the future.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you. My warning before my answer is to illustrate that but also others concept. Such as: why in the first do you have to put this kind of data in your table? (insert 'DB1.DBX1/2/3/...' have no meaning to me, context?) Don't you use an Entity Framework (or alike) to do it for you? In the first place, interfacing a controller directly to your database isn't a good thing to do. etc

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing to do is to switch from concatenated strings to parameters:

```
    for (int i=1; i<len; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1(Address) values(@Address)",con);
        smd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "DB1.DBX"+i.ToString()+";
        smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

**Note:** switching to parameterized query is not what solved the problem you reported, but it is required in order to immune your code from [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
What actually solved the problem you reported is removing the `''` you had in your code, as a_horse_with_no_name wrote in his comment.

The second thing I would suggest is to change the approach of executing multiple inserts in a loop to execute a single insert with multiple values.
This can be achieved by using a table valued parameter, but will require using a stored procedure and a user defined table type:

Create the user defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.udt_Address AS TABLE
(
    Address varchar(10)
)
```

Create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertToTable1
(
    @Addresses dbo.udt_Address READONLY
)
AS

INSERT INTO Table_1(Address)
SELECT Address
FROM @Addresses

GO
```

And the c# code would look like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    for (int i=1; i<len; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(string.Format("DB1.DBX{0}", i));
    }
SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("InsertToTable1",con);
smd.Parameters.Add("@Addresses", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```